# How to clone a repo using Libgit2Sharp

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

I am trying to clone a repository with the below C# code

```cs
try
{
  var result = Repository.Clone(remoteUrl, localPath);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

`Repository.Clone()` does not return, and there is no thrown exception.  Is there anything wrong with the code?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I know a lot of time has passed since this question was asked, but this is how I do it (in case it is still helpful):

```
Repository.Clone("https://repository.git", deployerPath, new CloneOptions()
{
    BranchName = "branch_to_pull_from",
    CredentialsProvider = CredentialsProvider(),
});
```

The **CredentialsProvider** method should return a **Credentials** object via the **CredentialsHandler** delegate, provided in the **LibGit2Sharp.Handlers** namespace.

By the way, I'm using LibGit2Sharp version **0.26.1**, in which an exception is actually thrown in this scenario.

Comment: And how shows the download status using winforms progressbar, please? ty!

Comment: You can use 2 Progress Handlers, LibGit2Sharp.Handlers.TransferProgressHandler and LibBit2Sharp.Handlers.CheckoutProgressHandler and add them to your CloneOptions as OnCheckoutProgress and OnTransferProgress.  I still can't get the Credentials part to work tho.

Comment: Is it possible to set configuration? i.e. core.longpaths = true?